# sqoop password file from local file system

Tags: sqoop

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:mysql:" --username sqoopuser --password-file HDFS directory
```

is working

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:mysql:" --username sqoopuser --password-file Local FS Directory
```

is not working . It is throwing a file does not exist error.

Sqoop Documentation says:

> Secure way of supplying password to the database. You should save the password in a file on the users home directory with 400 permissions and specify the path to that file using the --password-file argument, and is the preferred method of entering credentials. Sqoop will then read the password from the file and pass it to the MapReduce cluster using secure means with out exposing the password in the job configuration. The file containing the password can either be on the Local FS or HDFS.

I'm really not sure on how sqoop decides whether the path is HDFS or Local FS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your password are stored in `/home/${user}/password.file` (***Local FS***)

Instead of using

```
--password-file /home/${user}/password.file
```

use

```
--password-file file:///home/${user}/password.file
```

Comment: @sri Hi, I see you're new to SO (_Stack Overflow_). If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on other question which still don't have answers.